# How to validate variable in Symfony 1.4

Tags: validation, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I use Symfony 1.4.11. I have two tables **"companies" and "ads"**. When user add new ad, he can connect ad with his company.Before it I check, if user have company, for example I have variable `$has_company`, if  `$has_company==1`  - user has company, if `$has_company==0` he has not company. If user want connect company with ad, he must check checkbox  :-) So I want to validate checkbox, If user check checkbox, and he has not company,I want to show messages, that  first he must create company.... Is it possible? Can I use sfValidatorBoolean ? If yes, how to validate variable `has_company`? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a method in myUser class to check if the current user has a company (if your models user and company are linked).
And then, you can pass the result of this method in option of your form.
For validation, you can use a callback validator : http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/B-Validators#chapter_b_sub_sfvalidatorcallback

Comment: Thank you very much!sfValidatorCallback is what I need)You are the best;-) I also use **[this](http://symfony-world.blogspot.com/2011/03/symfony-validate-database-content.html)** article.

Comment: Hm, but I have liitle problem)when validation is pass,and I check checkbox,value does not set in db(

Answer (score 0):

you can use **halt_on_error** option like

```
$v = new sfValidatorAnd(
  array(
    new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 255)),
    new sfValidatorEmail(),
  ),
  array('halt_on_error' => true),
  array('invalid' => 'The input value must be an email with less than 255 characters.')
);
```